# Java Enum Static is not static

Tags: java, object, enums, nullpointerexception

I noticed something strange while using enums.
Let's assume I have the following class:

```java
public enum Test {

    TEST

    ;

    private static final File TEST_FILE = new File("test");
 
    
    Test() {
        test();
    }
        
    private void test() {
        System.out.println(TEST_FILE);
    }
}
```

Guess what `TEST_FILE` is?

You are correct. It is obviously `null`… what else?

But what resolves the issue?
Using the `static` constructor:

```java
static {
    System.out.println(TEST_FILE);
}
```

This might be obvious behavior for some — but nor for me.
This behavior surprises me.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How are enum constructors initialized? What is the order?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/NQndpr

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My example missed the most crucial part: The field needs to be `static`

Comment: (1) Because the `TEST` constant is being initialized before `TEST_FILE`. (2) Enum constants are initialized in the order they are declared, same as if they were just "normal" static fields (with inline initialization).

Comment: Note that `TEST` is basically shorthand for `public static final Test TEST = new Test();`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419519/enums-static-and-instance-blocks

Comment: Erm ... it >is< static.  You are just using a `static final` before it has been initialized.  You can get the same effect in an ordinary class if you have mutually dependent `static final` variables and you use private methods to access the variables "during initialization" in an attempt to resolve the cycle.  (You will see `null` ... like you are seeing in your example.)   Java doesn't stop you seeing the pre-initialized state of a `static final` variable ... if you try hard enough.